# The multi identifier couldn't be found error message?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able to add string "reviews" to database. I am required to work with subquery's.
I need to combine "UserID" from the "User" table with the "OutfitID" from the "Outfit" table column. That way I can tell which review belongs to which User and to which outfit.

First I tried this query:

```
SELECT Gebruiker.GebrID,Outfit.ID 
FROM Gebruiker 
INNER JOIN Outfit ON Outfit.GebrID = Gebruiker.GebrID 
WHERE Gebruiker.Alias = 'john'
INSERT INTO Review(GebrID,OutfitID,StukTekst) 
VALUES(Gebruiker.GebrID, Outfit.ID,'ziet er cool uit');
```

Now I want to add the data to the review table but I get this error message:
[image: error message]

This is my Database diagram:
[image: Database Diagram]

Comment: "I am required to work with subquery's" where are the subqueries?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, yeah thank you for the reminder. I have changed it to sql server only.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem.

Comment: How much more fun would this question have been, when the question had proper database description, and not a picture .  When using SSMS, rightclick on the table, Script Table as, Create to , New Query Editor Windows, and the copy/paste the `CREATE TABLE .....` statement would have been so much nicer! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are required to use subqueries, perhaps also use them.

You want to get values from user `John`, to insert into `Review`.

You could do this:

```
INSERT INTO Review(GebrID, OutfitID, StukTekst)
VALUES ((SELECT GebrID FROM Gebruikers WHERE Gebruiker.Alias = 'john'),
        (SELECT Outfit.ID FROM Outfit INNER JOIN Gebuikers ON Outfit.GebrID = Gebruikers.GebrID WHERE Gebruikers.Alias = 'john'),
        'ziet er cool uit'
       );
```

Now you're also using subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

The more direct way to do this would avoid the `values` clause and the repeated scalar subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO Review (GebrID, OutfitID, StukTekst)
SELECT Gebruiker.GebrID, Outfit.ID, 'ziet er cool uit'
FROM Gebruiker INNER JOIN Outfit ON Outfit.GebrID = Gebruiker.GebrID 
WHERE Gebruiker.Alias = 'john';
```

As for whether the meets somebody's arbitrary "subqueries" requirement is unclear. If that query returns multiple rows then it will insert them all unless that causes a violation for the insert operation.